# Syntax error in call statement in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I have written a simple test program to try subroutines and the call statement in Fortran. I am using gfortran compiler in GNU/Linux. I have declared 14 parameters which are numbered accordingly in my code. While my code works PERFECTLY WELL when I try to pass 11 of those arguments through the call statement, I encounter a rather strange 'SYNTAX ERROR' when I try to include a 12th argument and I try to pass 12 arguments through the call statement. What might the problem be and how might I fix it? Here is the program I am talking about

`

```
    program test

         IMPLICIT REAL*4(A-B,D-H,O-Z)
         IMPLICIT COMPLEX(C)
         COMPLEX*16 CQC,CQV

         parameter k1=2   
         parameter k2=2  
         parameter k3=2
         parameter k4=2
         parameter k5=2
         parameter k6=2
         parameter k7=2
         parameter k8=2
         parameter k9=2
         parameter k10=2
         parameter k11=2
         parameter k12=2
         parameter k13=2
         parameter k14=2

         call bins(k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k9, k10, k11, k12) 

    end program


    subroutine bins(k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k9, k10, k11, k12)

         integer k1, k2, k3, k4, k5

    end subroutine   `
```

Following is the error that I get when I include k12 in the 'call' statement and then compile it:

`

```
siddharth@siddharth-VBox:~/Desktop/Codes$ gfortran test6.for -o  test6.out
test6.for:23.72:

             call bins(k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k9, k10, k11, k12
                                                                    1
Error: Syntax error in argument list at (1)
test6.for:29.72:

        subroutine bins(k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6, k7, k8, k9, k10, k11, k1
                                                                    1
Error: Unexpected junk in formal argument list at (1)
test6.for:2.72:

        program test                                                    
                                                                    1
test6.for:31.72:

            integer k1, k2, k3, k4, k5                                 
                                                                    2
Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)
```

`

I reiterate that I don't encounter any problems in compiling when I include the arguments k1 to k11 in the call statement, its just the introduction of a 12th argument that introduces the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: assume you are using fixed form fortran you cant go past column 72.

Comment: you can use `-ffree-form` as an option to gfortran to tell it to use free form regardless of filename extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Files with a .for or .f extension, by convention, are treated as fixed form source.  Statements on fixed form lines must go in between columns 7 and 72, inclusive.  Note the column position in the error message - the end of your statement is being chopped off.

Fixed form source is also not sensitive to whitespace.  All the `parameter kxxx` assignment statements before the call statement don't do what you think.

Do not use fixed form source unless you are modifying existing legacy code.

Do not use implicit typing unless you are modifying existing legacy code (or perhaps engaging in some esoteric application of generic programming).  `IMPLICIT NONE` is your best friend.