# Syntax error in function arguments in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a sub routine file as follows

```
subroutine grids(Ngrids,gridsize,boundx,boundy,boundz,occmatrix,myid)

  implicit NONE

  integer           i,j,k,Ngrids, occmatrix(14,14,10)
  integer           locx,locy,locz,myid
  double precision  gridsize,boundx,boundy,boundz


  do i = 1, 14
     do j = 1, 14
        do k = 1, 10
           occmatrix(i,j,k) = 0
        enddo
     enddo
  enddo

  open (13, file = 'grid_data.9deg')    
  write(*,'(A,i2)'),' READING GRID FILE ON PROC.....',myid
  read(13,*) Ngrids,gridsize
  read(13,*) boundx,boundy,boundz       
  do i = 1, Ngrids
    read(13,*) locx, locy, locz
    occmatrix(locx,locy,locz) = 1 
  enddo 
  close(13)

  return
end
```

It gives the following syntax error in compiling

```
subroutine grids(Ngrids,gridsize,boundx,boundy,boundz,occmatrix,my
                                                                  1
Error: Unexpected junk in formal argument list at (1)
```

It used to run well before

Comment: How do you compile, what suffix does your file have?

Comment: What is the extension of your file? Depending on the extension, the compiler might ignore everything else after a certain column number. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335487/syntax-error-in-call-statement-in-fortran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would believe, your line is to long. Did you add a new argument? Your code looks like free form, but it might be the compiler tried to apply fixed form due to a .f suffix in the filename or something like that. Convince the compiler to assume free formatted source code (by compiler options or usually a .f90 suffix).

Even in free formatted files your line width is limited and you should break longer lines, which would for example look like:

```
subroutine grids( Ngrids,gridsize,boundx,boundy,boundz, &
  &               occmatrix,myid )
```

If you are stuck with fixed format you need to indicate a continuation line by a non blank character in column 6.

Here is how it looks like in fixed form:

```
      subroutine grids(Ngrids,gridsize,boundx,boundy,boundz,
     &                 occmatrix,myid)
```

**Please** do not use fixed form anymore! Instead, change your files to end with .f90, most compilers recognize this for free formatted code.